# Cannot load Angular2 child components

Tags: angular

### Product-List Component.ts

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {IProduct}  from './product';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls:['app/products/product-list.component.css']
})

export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit{
    pageTitle:string = 'Product List';
    imageWidth:number = 50;
    imageMargin:number = 2;
    showImage:boolean=false;
    listFilter:string='cart';
    products: IProduct[] = [
        {
        "productId": 1,
        "productName": "Leaf Rake",
        "productCode": "GDN-0011",
        "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
        "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
        "price": 19.95,
        "starRating": 3.2,
        "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png"
    },
    {
        "productId": 2,
        "productName": "Garden Cart",
        "productCode": "GDN-0023",
        "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
        "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
        "price": 32.99,
        "starRating": 4.2,
        "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png"
    }
    ];

    toggleImage():void{
        this.showImage = !this.showImage;
    }

    ngOnInit():void{
        console.log('In OnInit');
    }
}
```

### My Products-List.component.html

```
<ai-star>/ai-star>
```

### Nested Component

```
import {Component, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ai-star',
    templateUrl:'app/shared/start.component.html',
    styleUrls:['app/shared/star.component.css']
})

export class StarComponent implements OnChanges{
    rating : number=4;
    starWidth : number;

    ngOnChanges():void {
        this.starWidth =  this.rating * 86/5;
    }
}
```

### My app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from '../app.component';
import {ProductListComponent} from '../products/product-list.component';
import {StarComponent} from '../shared/star.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule,FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,
                  ProductListComponent,
                  StarComponent
               ],

  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I execute this code ( npm start) I get the error

> 'ai-star' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'ai-star' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

How do I load a child component. I am using VSCode .

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: Have you added `StarComponent` to declarations array in app.module file?

Comment: In the html ,among other things I am using the tags .. <ai-star> </ai-star>. This is which causing the error

Comment: Yes I have added StarComponent in my declarations array. i've provided the code for it as well

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo when you write the code here, but this line `<ai-star>/ai-star>` in
`Products-List.component.html` should be `<ai-star></ai-star>`

Comment: nope..thats a typo while i wrote here . not there in the code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your error you are getting continues like something along these lines...

```
If 'ai-star' is a Webcomponent then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the NgModule...
```

So you could try and do that - in your NgModule, add the `schemas` like so:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [ ... ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA], // add this!
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: Okay, thought it would be worth a shot to try at least :) Could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker. To me, the code looks pretty fine and nothing obvious jumps out...